# Understanding input_shape parameter in LSTM with Keras

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, keras, lstm, dimension

I'm trying to use [the example described in the Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) named "Stacked LSTM for sequence classification" (see code below) and can't figure out the `input_shape` parameter in the context of my data.

I have as input a matrix of sequences of 25 possible characters encoded in integers to a padded sequence of maximum length 31. As a result, my `x_train` has the shape `(1085420, 31)` meaning `(n_observations, sequence_length)`.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

data_dim = 16
timesteps = 8
num_classes = 10

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))

# Generate dummy validation data
x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=64, epochs=5,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

In this code `x_train` has the shape `(1000, 8, 16)`, as for an array of 1000 arrays of 8 arrays of 16 elements. There I get completely lost on what is what and how my data can reach this shape.

Looking at Keras doc and various tutorials and Q&A, it seems I'm missing something obvious. Can someone give me a hint of what to look for ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So data input to `LSTM` should have shape `(nb_of_samples, seq_len, features)`. In your case - as your feature vector consist of only one integer - you should resize your `X_train` should have shape `(1085420, 31, 1)`. As this representation is not very suited for neural networks - you should either:

1. Change your representation to *one-hot* encoding - then your output should have shape `(1085420, 31, 25)`.
2. Use [`Embedding`](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) layer and leave `(1085420, 31)` shape.